# Thermal harmonic oscillator as bose factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, bosons

Let us consider a harmonic oscillator $V=\frac{1}{2}m\omega x^2$ in contact with a heat reservoir. Take the partition function
$$Z=\sum e^{-\beta \hbar \omega (n+1/2)}=e^{-\beta \hbar \omega /2} \sum e^{-\beta \hbar \omega n}=e^{-\beta \hbar \omega /2}\frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}}=\frac{1}{2\sinh{(\beta\hbar\omega/2)}}.$$
Then we have the mean energy
$$U=-\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\coth(\beta\hbar\omega/2)=\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\left( \frac{e^{\beta\hbar\omega/2}+e^{-\beta\hbar\omega/2}}{e^{\beta\hbar\omega/2}-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega/2}}\right) =\hbar\omega\left( n_B(\beta\hbar\omega)+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
where $$n_B(x)=\frac{1}{e^x-1}$$
is called Bose factor.

Now, I want to interpret it by relating it to a boson in harmonic potential. One way is to identify a single excited level of $n_B(\beta\hbar\omega)$. However, it is not the only one, and it has been suggested to interpret it as "a boson orbital which is occupied by $n_B$ bosons." However, I can't imagine what orbital it is talking about, and what it means by $n_B$ bosons. To me, an excited state of energy level $n_B$ is all there is.

Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a system with a *single* level of energy $\hbar\omega$ and it is occupied by $n_B$ particles (necessarily bosons, of course), then the energy of the system is $n_B\hbar\omega$, which is equivalent to a single Harmonic oscillator at the $n_B$-excited level.